# Finding the points of a line with a known direction and distance joining 2 ellipses

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

I have 2 ellipses, say $e_1$ and $e_2$.

I want to draw a line $l$ connecting $e_1$ and $e_2$ in a known direction $(u,v)$, with a known distance $d$.

Is there a way to solve for the points of intersection of $l$ on both $e_1$ and $e_2$? I am implementing this in software and the only way I have thought of is testing every point on $e_1$, but was thinking if there is an analytical way.

Answer (score 1):

Because you know the direction $(u,v)$ of your connecting line,
you can imagine a collection of parallel
lines intersecting $e_1$ and $e_2$, all in direction $(u,v)$:

---

[image: TwoEllipses]

---

It is relatively easy to compute the intersection of a line and an ellipse.
E.g., here is [one explication](http://www.analyzemath.com/EllipseProblems/ellipse_line_int.html);
[here](https://gieseanw.wordpress.com/2013/07/19/an-analytic-solution-for-ellipse-and-line-intersection/) is another.
If the intersection points are $p_1$ and $p_2$ for a line $L$, you want to solve
$||p_1 - p_2|| = d$ to find the line $L$ whose intersection points are $d$ apart.

Answer (score 0):

We can use Lagrange's multipliers with 2 constraints( the two equations for the ellipses) and the minimized function.